# JQM selectmenu first option blank when echoing php-based select items

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile

I'm populating a jQuery Mobile select menu in a form from mySQL database using this php:

```
$OTsql = "SELECT * FROM OrderTypes";
$OTresult = mysql_query($OTsql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($OTresult))
{
    $OTid=$row["id_ot"];
    $OTname=$row["orderTypes"];
    $OToptions.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$OTid\">".$OTname;
}
```

the html is this:

```
<label>Order Type:</label><br>
<select name="orderType" id="orderType" data-overlay-theme="e" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="arrow-d">
    <option id="0" value=""> Select Order Type </option>
    <option>
        <? echo $OToptions ?>
    </option>
</select>
```

While I can click on the selectmenu and see the options listed from the database, it shows a blank (no text listed on the selectmenu button itself) and when I click the menu the top spot is a blank placeholder.
I've tried a variety of jQuery options like variations of this which I've found here at SO:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
   $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = true;
});
```

The bigger problem (I could possibly live without there being the first option listed by default on the button or "Select Order Type" as the item listed on the button--which would be ideal), but when I go to save a pre-existing form, it changes whatever had been selected there to a blank in the database record.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm not even sure if I'm going about this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 $OToptions.="<option value=\"$OTid\">".$OTname."</option>";  


<select name="orderType" id="orderType" data-overlay-theme="e" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="arrow-d">
<option id="0" value=""> Select Order Type </option>

 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($OTresult))
   {
     $OTid=$row["id_ot"];
     $OTname=$row["orderTypes"];
    echo "<option value=\"$OTid\">".$OTname."</option>";
    }
   ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: This did the trick! You all are awesome! I'm looking forward to exploring some of the other options shown here, but for now this one works for me, thanks Chinnu R!

Comment: NP, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing your options wrong. Try this:

```
$OTsql = "SELECT * FROM OrderTypes";
$OTresult = mysql_query($OTsql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($OTresult))
{
    $OTid=$row["id_ot"];
    $OTname=$row["orderTypes"];
    $OToptions.="<option value=\"$OTid\">".$OTname ."</option>";
}
```

HTML

```
<label>Order Type:</label><br>
<select name="orderType" id="orderType" data-overlay-theme="e" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="arrow-d">
    <option id="0" value=""> Select Order Type </option>
    <?php echo $OToptions ?>
</select>
</label>
```

BTW, mysql_* functions are deprecated. Change to mysqli_* or _PDO functions

Comment: will plan on the mysqli changes, thanks for the insight. Your removal of my extra <option></option> in the html also helped with some other select menus that were populating but not showing the placeholder text. I'd +1 but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code, I expect the generated output to be:

```
...
<option>
   <option>....</option>
   ...
   <option>....</option>
</option>
...
```

which is wrong. Try to remove the outer  tags by modifying your html markup:

```
<select name="orderType" id="orderType" data-overlay-theme="e" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="arrow-d">
    <option id="0" value=""> Select Order Type </option>
    <? echo $OToptions ?>
</select>
```

Additionally, just for an improved style, I suggest you to reformat the PHP part in a more readable way, e.g.:

```
$OToptions .= '<option value="'.$OTid.'">'.$OTname;
```

Comment: I'm going to experiment with the improved style. I appreciate your answer!